# Excel - sum an array then perform another calculation

Tags: arrays, excel

I wish to use year in this Excel LET function to be used in place of Z3 so that year will increment for each row of the array.

How could this be rewritten to make it work?

```
=LET(year,SEQUENCE(ModelDuration,,StartYear),
totrow,BYROW(AA3#:AT3#,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)/(1+(1+DR)/(1+TPI)-1)^(Z3-StartYear))),
totrow)
```

Comment: Can you state what your question without all the extra formula stuff that seems to not play any role here. You want to replace 'Z3' with 'year' but you want 'year' to increment for each row of the array. Do you want the other instance of your 'year' in that formula to also increase for each row? Are you familiar with the function ROW() which will just give you the current row of your cell?

Comment: Better than ROW function, ROWS function will grant you an increment of 1 by each row. If your list start form A1, ROW and ROWS are the same. Otherwise you might use ROWS and set the range according to your need. For example: if your data start in A5, you can use `ROWS(A$5:A5)` to get an index for your list.

Comment: Untested: `=LET(year,SEQUENCE(ModelDuration,,StartYear),
totrow,BYROW(Z3#:AT3#,LAMBDA(x,SUM(drop(x,,1))/(1+(1+DR)/(1+TPI)-1)^(take(x,,1)-StartYear))),
totrow)` better to post sample data and expected output.

Comment: You may need to remove the `#` after `Z3` if it's not a spill range: `Z3:AT3#`

Comment: To @P.b The above formula you provided worked absolutely perfectly.  Many thanks for your help.